# How to add values to textbox array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<input name="member_name" id="member_name" />
```

I am trying to add multiple values to hidden text box array using jquery.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="member_names[]" id="member_names">
```

```js
$('input[name="member_names[]"]').val($('#member_name').val());
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? please provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use multiple value of type hidden. If you want this , you have to use a separator for multiple value in single hidden type.

Answer (score 0):

Create a javascript array and store values in that array, than using JSON.stringify function to set the values of input.

This method will assign the array values to input in comma separated form.

```
var elementsArray = [];
elementsArray.push('1');
elementsArray.push('2');
elementsArray.push('3');

$('#input_hidden_field').val(JSON.stringify(elementsArray));
```